# How to print array in magento 2?

Tags: log, magento-2.1

How can i print array values in magento 2?
I am using below code to print log in magento 2 but it will only print string values.

```
\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
    ->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->debug('message');
```

Thanks for your reply in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

**OLD WAY**

```
   \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
        ->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->debug(print_r(['a' => 'b'], true));
```

**NEW WAY**

```
STEP 1:  Add object in construction()
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        parent::__construct($context);
   }
STEP :2 Use logger in function where you want 
            $this->_logger->addDebug("=======START ORDER======"); 
            $this->_logger->addDebug(json_encode($order->getData()));
            $this->_logger->addDebug("=======END ORDER======");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing an array to debug you can use:

```
debug(print_r($arrayValues, true));
```

Also if you are using IDE like phpstorm you can see if there is a toArray method available.

Comment: `print_r` by default doesn't return value. You have to pass second parameter `true`

Comment: you are correct, will edit