# Log printing is not working in Magento 2.2.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I have tried to print a log in Magento 2.2.2 but its not printing any log in debug.log file. I am using xampp server with php version 7.1.7

```
\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->debug(print_r(['getCountries' => $countryCodes], true));
```

Let me know if i need to do any extra setting.

Thanks

Comment: You have answer here [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125829/how-to-print-array-in-magento-2)
I think it's dublicate qiestion.

Comment: @btek, I have already tried same link but its not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enable log printing you need to set configuration from backend.

> Goto Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Log to
>   File to Yes.

Comment: I can't change, field is disabales. any idea?

Comment: @ChiragPatel Please unchecked the checkbox besides the field and you will able to change its setting.